# Sort list by ids

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

I want to be able to sort this list by each ID using jquery or javascript. So far i've used this but it's not working. Can anyone help please?

```
    $(".select-sections li").sort(function(a, b) {
  return parseInt(a.id) - parseInt(b.id);
}).each(function() {
  var elem = $(this);
  elem.remove();
  $(elem).appendTo(".select-sections");
});

<ul class="select-sections">
    <li id="1508931954" class="cart-select cart-mode-cart">1 </li>
    <li id="1508932512" class="cart-select cart-mode-cart">13 </li>
    <li id="1508932519" class="cart-select cart-current cart-mode-cart">14 </li>
    <li id="1508931962" class="cart-select cart-mode-cart">2 </li>
    <li id="1508931989" class="cart-select cart-mode-cart">3 </li>
    <li id="1508932219" class="cart-select cart-mode-cart">Bay 10 </li>
    <li id="1508932254" class="cart-select cart-mode-cart">Bay 11 </li>
    <li id="1508932257" class="cart-select cart-mode-cart">Bay 12 </li>
    <li id="1508932176" class="cart-select cart-mode-cart"><Bay 4 </li>
    <li id="1508932181" class="cart-select cart-mode-cart">Bay 5 </li>
    <li id="1508932186" class="cart-select cart-mode-cart">Bay 6 </li>
    <li id="1508932191" class="cart-select cart-mode-cart">Bay 7 </li>
    <li id="1508932209" class="cart-select cart-mode-cart">Bay 8 </li>
    <li id="1508932214" class="cart-select cart-mode-cart">Bay 9 </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: [here's an article](http://trentrichardson.com/2013/12/16/sort-dom-elements-jquery/) which shows you how to sort DOM elements with jquery

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/z8svx8gg/ -- what you've done here works for me. Maybe you didn't reference jQuery in your html

Comment: Are you getting an error? It works fine when tested.

Comment: It's still not working https://jsfiddle.net/89m9sdpo/